# How to fix/arrange according to the design

Tags: html, css

I am doing some school **css** projects and I was trying to follow this layout but
I have no luck I am getting this weird uneven image size. I am using Bootstrap

Please see this link for the layout: https://www.figma.com/file/9OKYlZxHZIhkaCS84THrYW/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1

And here is a screenshot of what it looks like on my end: https://ibb.co/SfXqBCg
And here is my code

```css
.logo-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.custome-button-design {
  background-color: #e74d57;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.img-custom-size {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="upper-nav-background ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row p-2 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg ">
          <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/hqd.svg" class="logo-image " alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm d-flex justify-content-center custom-margin-bottom">
          <button class="custome-button-design custom-fonts">BUTTON</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm  d-flex justify-content-center p-2">
          <div class="row header-details-sm">
            <div class="col">
              <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/hqm.svg" class="img-custom-size" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col custom-fonts">
              <p>Email</p>
              <p>needhelp@asiapro.com</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-sm d-flex justify-content-center p-2">
          <div class="row header-details-sm">
            <div class="col">
              <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/hqm.svg" class="img-custom-size" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col custom-fonts">
              <p>Phone</p>
              <p>123-456-789</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-sm d-flex justify-content-center p-2">
          <div class="row header-details-sm">
            <div class="col">
              <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/hqm.svg" class="img-custom-size" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col custom-fonts">
              <p>Address</p>
              <p>Japan Tokyo</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is bootstrap required? this looks pretty easy but could be a nice way to learn, try some more and won't recommend asking here if its a school project, You learn more if you try more on your own rather than asking for help. Just a hint the elements should be inline

Comment: Please include the pictures directly to SO (upload them here) instead of uploading it to an external hoster. The links maybe become invalid or deleted. In that case the question would hold no further value. Also if you using bootstrap, state what version you using and tag the question accordingly!

Answer (score -1):

Definitely have to tweak this further but that would be my approach:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family:  sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
 background-color: #C6C6D1;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-around;
 padding: 1rem;
}

h2 {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 6px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

button {
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: #F86B6B;
  border: none;
}

.address {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.address svg{
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  color: white;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #F86B6B;
  border-radius: 999px;
}

.address p {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<h2>SCHOOL-PROJECT-LOGO</h2>
<button>BUTTON</button>
<div class="address">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M16 12a4 4 0 10-8 0 4 4 0 008 0zm0 0v1.5a2.5 2.5 0 005 0V12a9 9 0 10-9 9m4.5-1.206a8.959 8.959 0 01-4.5 1.207" />
  <p>Email<br />email@test.com</p>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="address">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3 5a2 2 0 012-2h3.28a1 1 0 01.948.684l1.498 4.493a1 1 0 01-.502 1.21l-2.257 1.13a11.042 11.042 0 005.516 5.516l1.13-2.257a1 1 0 011.21-.502l4.493 1.498a1 1 0 01.684.949V19a2 2 0 01-2 2h-1C9.716 21 3 14.284 3 6V5z" />
</svg>
  <p>Phone<br />123-456-789</p>
</div>
<div class="address">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6" />
</svg>
<p>Address<br />Japan Tokyo</p>
</div>

</div>
```